# Flutter Web got really slow on Google Chrome Mac M1

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

My flutter website got really slow on my Google Chrome (mac M1).

The console shows no errors, and I have tested on other browsers and desktops and it works fine.

It's hard to find the cause when there are no errors. Does anyone has an idea?

P.S. This is the website: https://polys.art . It only gets slow after connecting it to web3 by pressing `connect wallet` which will reveal another UI.

Comment: Looks like you've used a single child scrollview or similar which is terrible for performance

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla what should I use instead to make my page scrollable?

Comment: You'll need a CustomScrollView using Slivers

Answer (score 2):

Looks like building with `html` instead of `canvaskit` solves the problem. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

To override the web renderer at runtime:

```
Build the app with the auto option.
Insert a <script> tag in web/index.html file before the main.dart.js script.
Set window.flutterWebRenderer to "canvaskit" or "html":
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let useHtml = // ...
    if(useHtml) {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
    } else {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "canvaskit";
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```